# jQuery - load response string as a new page

Tags: jquery, html, string, load

I call a perl script on the server side that build the whole html code of the new page and I want to load this new page when the script has finished. Here is the code I tried:

```
$j.post(url, {
    type: type,
    razname: raz,
    releasedocs: releases
},
function (data) {
        window.location.href = data;
        hide('statusContent');
        hide('statusFrame');
});
```

data is actually the whole html code in a string but the href expects a file.
How can I load this code in a new page (back button of the browser should go back to the page from where it has been called) without writing it in a file?

Comment: how can html code supposed to be a new page? what route would that page be? you could replace the complete current page but you won't be able to open it in a new page since there is no route defined..

Comment: Ok,understood! Thanks for the quick answer! Is there a way to do it like this:
`<a href="perlscript">link</a>`
but during the script execution time show a loading picture?

Comment: you need to use $.ajax to do this. either your perlscript creats a .html file where you can be redirected to or you stay on your current page and replace the whole content with your response. either way you can use the ajaxStart() and ajaxStop() functions to show/hide a spinner gif during the loading phase